# Filling and reading elements of Mat in opencv

Tags: opencv

I have this simple question.I want to create a normal 2D Matrix to use as `bin` to put integers, and increment some elements, but it doesn't work,why?it just prints some unknown symboes.
here is my code

```
Mat img = imread("img.jpg", 0);
Mat bin = Mat::zeros(img.size(),CV_8U);//also tried 8UC1
for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{   
    bin.at<uchar>(i, 50) = 200;
    cout << bin.at<uchar>(i, 50) << endl;
   //(bin.at<uchar>(i,50))++;//if above statement works then I will use this incrementer
}
```

Comment: cout << int(bin.at<uchar>(i, 50)) << endl;

Comment: @Miki thanks Miki ,but can you tell me please what is the problem? why without int(...) it doesn't work?

Comment: since it's a char, you're printing the ascii character, not the real value. Casting to int shows the real value

Comment: is there any Mat of type int?I wanted to define as CV_8S but again I need to cast to int

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? This doesn't seem a _good_ way ;D

Comment: I did it with Cv_8S but again this doesn't print  without casting `cout << bin.at<int>(100, 50)<< endl;}`

Comment: I am trying just to make a normal algebraic matrix with same dimension of picture and then use it as bin,to increment some elements in case of some events

Comment: you need `CV_32S`, since `int` are 32 bits. `CV_8S` is the equivalent of `char` (or `signed char`). To have a matrix of integer the same size of your image, you can simply do: `Mat1i bin(img.rows, img.cols, 0)` (note that `Mat1i` is a shortcut for `Mat_<int>`). Then you can modify each value simply with `int value = bin(row, col);` or `bin(row, col) = value;`

Comment: oh that's great help,thank u very much ,u could do it as answer so i put tik on it

Comment: Well,surely it is pretty basic question,but I couldn't find anything related,using google,or searching documentation,and it took a day from me and my nerves of course ;)  so maybe it will help some beginners like me

Comment: Post an answer with the correct solution, and than accept your own answer ;D